# $A,\ B\subseteq R$ and $m*(A)<\infty$, show that $m^*(B\cap A^c)\geq m^*(B)-m^*(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

1.$A,\ B\subseteq R$ and $m^*(A)<\infty$, show that $  m^*(B\cap A^c)\geq m^*(B)-m^*(A)$; here $m^*$ is  the outer measure.

My work-
we can write,

$m^*(B)\leq m^*((B\cap A^c)\cup A)\leq m^*(B\cap A^c)+m^*(A)$,     by sigma additivity of outer measure.

then, $m^*(B)\leq m^*(B\cap A^c)+m^*(A)$

since,  $m^*(A)$ is finite, we can substract it from both side.
hence, $m^*(B)-m^*(A)\leq m^*(B\cup A^c)$

Is this correct proof?

2.In the second part, I'm asked to prove $m^*((a,b)\cup(c,d))=m^*(a,b)+m^*(c,d)$ where (a,b) and (c,d) are disjoint intervals. Should I use the above results for the proof?

Since outer measure is not additive , I don't think we can use additivity here.

Comment: In the givens, is it supposed to be $m^*(A) < \infty$ or $m_*(A) < \infty$? It looks like you may have mixed up some $\cup$ and $\cap$ symbols. I'd use more parentheses at $m^*(B \cap A^c \cup A)$ - I don't know a convention on whether $X \cap Y \cup Z$ means $(X \cap Y) \cup Z$ or $X \cap (Y \cup Z)$.

Comment: I'm sorry about the mixed up. I edited now. I hope now it's correct.